# How to get the dominant color in an image with go and imagemagick

Tags: go, imagemagick, color-palette

I want extract dominant colors from png, jpeg, svg and etc.
I haved try this code but sometimes the generated palette is not correct.

```golang
// GET image colors
    mw.QuantizeImage(5, mw.GetImageColorspace(), 0, imagick.DITHER_METHOD_NO, false)
    _, allColors := mw.GetImageHistogram()

    for i, c := range allColors {
        if i > 4 {
            break
        }
        h, s, l := c.GetHSL()

        // "github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful"
        cf := colorful.Hsl(h*360, s, l)

        result = append(result, cf.Hex())
    }
```

What is the best method to extract the dominant colors?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "dominant colors". Most-frequently used? How fuzzy do you want to match colors? Are you just looking for hues? How many "dominant colors" are you looking for? What threshold makes a color "dominant" in your use case?

Comment: I want create a palette of 5 colors that represent the image.

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over all color items & call `(*PixelWand)GetColorCount` to determine the frequency.

```golang
mw.QuantizeImage(5, mw.GetImageColorspace(), 0, imagick.DITHER_METHOD_NO, false)
_, allColors := mw.GetImageHistogram()
var (
    mostUsedColor *PixelWand
    mostUsedCount uint
)
for _, c := range allColors {
    count := c.GetColorCount()
    if count > mostUsedCount {
        mostUsedColor = c
        mostUsedCount = count
    }
}
```

Comment: I sort the array with this code
```
sort.SliceStable(allColors, func(i, j int) bool {
  return allColors[i].GetColorCount() > allColors[j].GetColorCount()
 })
```